# Typeclass and the scala Collection Interface

Tags: scala, collections, typeclass

I am trying to implement a function that would work on types that have a `map` and a `flatMap` method. I have already made it for `Traversable`, but this does not include `Future` and `Option` directly. So I have decided to go with my own interface, using a typeclass:

```
trait CanMap[A, M[_]] {
  def map[B](l: M[A])(f: A => B): M[B]
  def flatMap[B](l: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

I already implemented this for `Option`:

```
  implicit def canmapopt[A] = new CanMap[A, Option] {
    def map[B](l: Option[A])(f: A => B): Option[B] = l.map(f)
    def flatMap[B](l: Option[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = l.flatMap(f)
  }
```

and this one works very well. Now I wanted to implement it for any subtype of `Traversable`,  I tried an implementation very close to the one for Option:

```
  implicit def canmaptrav[A, B, T[B] <: Traversable[B]] = new CanMap[A, T] {
    def map[B](l: T[A])(f: A => B): T[B] = l.map(f)
    def flatMap[B](l: T[A])(f: A => T[B]): T[B] = l.flatMap(f)
  }
```

but I get the error:

```
  type mismatch;  found   : Traversable[B]  required: T[B]  Note: implicit method canmaptrav is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
```

for the return type of `l.map`. I cannot understand why `l.map(f)` would return a `Traversable` and not the specific type `T[B]`. So I tried to explicitelly put the right type of CanBuildFrom in the context:

```
  implicit def canmaptrav[A, B, T[B] <: Traversable[B]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T[A], B, T[B]]) = new CanMap[A, T] {
    def map[B](l: T[A])(f: A => B): T[B] = l.map(f)
    def flatMap[B](l: T[A])(f: A => T[B]): T[B] = l.flatMap(f)
  }
```

The error persists.

Any idea where I went wrong? It might be obvious but I am getting confused with the generic type signatures I guess.

## Update: Solution

First of all, as the answers pointed out, `CanMap` is mostly a Functor/Monad, so if you dare, you can use *scalaz* to implement this. However, if you are like me and want to try without it, here is the solution, based on the answer by Kipton Barros:

```
trait CanMap[A, B, M[_]] {
  def map(l: M[A])(f: A => B): M[B]
  def flatMap(l: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}

implicit def canmapopt[A, B] = new CanMap[A, B, Option] {
  def map(l: Option[A])(f: A => B): Option[B] = l.map(f)
  def flatMap(l: Option[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = l.flatMap(f)
}

implicit def canmaptrav[A, B, M[+_]](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]], ev: M[A] => TraversableLike[A, M[A]], eb: M[B] => TraversableLike[B, M[B]]) = new CanMap[A, B, M] {
  def map(l: M[A])(f: (A) => B): M[B] = l.map(f)
  def flatMap(l: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B] = l.flatMap[B, M[B]] { (a: A) =>
    f(a)
  }
}
```

The trick is to use an implicit conversion `M[A] => TraversableLike[A, M[A]]` instead of trying to subtype `Traversable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that there's a lot going on "under the hood" in the `Traversable` `map` method. It does a bit of work to return the most specific collection type, which is why you need `CanBuildFrom`. The second problem is that `Option` does not implement the `Traversable` interface, so its `map` method *doesn't* take a `CanBuildFrom`.

Here's the closest I could get,

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.TraversableLike

trait CanMap[A, M[_]] {
  def map[B](l: M[A])(f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]]): M[B]
}

object Test {

  // ugly hack to work around nonexistent CanBuildFrom for Option
  implicit def optionBuilder[A, B]: CanBuildFrom[Option[A], B, Option[B]] = null

  implicit def canmapopt[A] = new CanMap[A, Option] {
    def map[B](l: Option[A])(f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Option[A], B, Option[B]]): Option[B] = l.map(f)
  }

  implicit def canmaptrav[A, M[_]](implicit ev: M[A] => TraversableLike[A, M[A]]) = new CanMap[A, M] {
    def map[B](l: M[A])(f: (A) => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]]): M[B] = l.map(f)
  }

  // example usage

  def mapper[A, B, M[_]](l: M[A])(f: A => B)(implicit cm: CanMap[A,M], bf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]]) = {
    cm.map(l)(f)
  }
  mapper(List(1,2,3))(_ + 1)          // List(2,3,4)
  mapper(Some(2): Option[Int])(_ + 1) // Some(3)
  // (cast to Option[Int] is needed to find the canmapopt implicit)
}
```

By the way, the implicit conversion to `TraversableLike` makes this also work with arrays,

```
 mapper(Array(1,2,3))(_ + 1)         // Array(2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Excellent! the `TraversableLike` implicit conversion is cool :)
I  had to adapt your solution a bit, moving the `CanBuildFrom` as an implicit to `canmaptrav`, so that it doesn't "poison" the `canmapopt`. To be able to implement the `flatMap`, I also had to add another implicit `CanBuildFrom` for type `M[B]` to `canmaptrav`. `B` is then now a parameter in `CanMap[A, B, M[_]]` and not anymore to the functions.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Including type `B` in `CanMap` simplifies things a lot, but the disadvantage is that each `CanMap` object only maps to one specific type. I looked at the Scalaz. They completely avoid `CanBuildFrom`, which has upsides (simpler) and downsides (target type not as specific; won't work automatically with arrays for example).

Comment: I don't really have the issue of `B` having to be a specific type as it's also a parameter of the implicits providing the CanMap. So it's made concrete dynamically by scala depending on where I use it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I tried your two failed attempts and didn't got much out of it. Then I decided to go simple and do my own CanMap implementation. I ended up with this:

```
  def canmaptrav[A] = new CanMap[A, Traversable]{
    def map[B](l: Traversable[A])(f: A => B): Traversable[B]= l.map(f)
    def flatMap[B](l: Traversable[A])(f: A => Traversable[B]): Traversable[B] = l.flatMap(f)
  }
```

Looking exactly the `CanMap[_,Option]`. Assuming the subtypes you are looking for is for use cases like this:

```
canmaptrav[Int].map(List(1,2,3,4))(_ + 1)       //> res0: Traversable[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5)
canmaptrav[Int].map(Vector(1,2,3,4))(_ + 1)     //> res1: Traversable[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Now, if you want res1 and res0 types to be the concrete types (List, Vector) than the approach will have to indeed rely on the `CanBuildFrom` from.

BTW, you know that the `CanMap` is almost the Monad interface, right?

Comment: yep, I had done that, but I wanted to get the right type out of the map/flatMap, that's why I went down the crazy road of `CanBuildFrom`.

Answer (score 2):

[Scalaz](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) already includes these typeclasses and they are called `Monad` and `Functor`. A short example:

```
// map
def foo[F[_] : Functor](xs: F[Int]) = xs.map(_ + 1)

scala> foo(List(1,2,3))
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

// flatMap
def flatten[M[_] : Monad](xs: M[M[Int]]) = xs.flatMap(identity)

scala> flatten(List(List(1,2,3)))
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

**edit**:

The functor instance for `Future` could look like this:

```
implicit object FutureFunctor extends Functor[Future] {
  def map[A,B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => B) = fa.map(f)
}
```

Comment: thanks, indeed, scalaz provides everything I need, but I wanted to do it without the whole scalaz library. In particular because I looked at the code, and I really didn't get how to use it, I couldn't even get it to download as a dependence. Scalaz looks cool, but it's too complex to start with just to get a Monad typeclass.